# How to achieve one to one mapping between elements just like dictionaries but allowing duplicates also?

Tags: python, dictionary, xlrd

I have an excel file containing data something similar to this:

```
ColumnA   ColumnB
   A        aaa
   B        eee
   A        ccc
   A        ddd
   B        fff
```

As we can see there are multiple rows having the same data **A** or **B** in **columnA** but corresponding to different data in **columnB**.

I need to find a way so as to have this data of **columnA** and **columnB** mapped one to one with each other e.g. `A:aaa,B:eee,A:ccc,A:ddd,B:fff` etc

I know dictionary will not allow duplicates, thus tried **defaultdict** construct from **collections** but it will give output as
`defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {u'A': [u'aaa', u'ccc'], u'B': [u'eee']})` which I don't need because it maps **columnA** data to multiple elements of **columnB**.
What I need specifically is this data in a list for example,

```
data[0] will have A:aaa
data[1] will have B:eee
```

My code with **defaultdict** as follows:

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)

def get_data():
    filename = "Demo.xlsx"
    exl_file = open_workbook(filename)
    sheet = exl_file.sheet_by_index(0)
    for row_index in range(1,4):
            col_a_data = sheet.cell(row_index,0).value
            col_b_data = sheet.cell(row_index,1).value
            data[col_a_data].append(col_b_data)

get_data()

print data
```

Is there any data structure available in Python which can help me achieve this ?

Comment: You could store your data as `{ 0 : {u'A': u'aaa'}, 1: {u'B' :u'eeee'} }`

Comment: What's the nature of `aaa` data? What you have described is basically a list of lists. By the way, very nice and complete question. You included everything needed to provide a complete answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking to just store your data as a list of dictionaries?
If so, this should work (untested). If not, how do you want to store your data?

```
from xlrd import open_workbook


data = []

def get_data():
    filename = "Demo.xlsx"
    exl_file = open_workbook(filename)
    sheet = exl_file.sheet_by_index(0)
    for row_index in range(1,4):
            col_a_data = sheet.cell(row_index,0).value
            col_b_data = sheet.cell(row_index,1).value
            data.append({col_a_data:col_b_data});

get_data()

print data
```

Comment: Wow, such a quick and nice solution. That's exactly what I needed. But what those curly braces exactly do/mean here` {col_a_data:col_b_data}` ?

Comment: Thats creating a dictionary where col_a_data is the key and col_b_data is the value.